# Ubuntu Dock disappeared on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, dock, ubuntu-dock

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my machine yesterday.

It had a launch bar/dock at the left of the screen yesterday. But not remembering what I had done yesterday, I somehow realized that I made dock disappear.

It now looks like in the screenshots:

[image: desktop]

[image: start menu(windows key)]

How will I bring Ubuntu dock back to actual desktop?